# Why is SSD peak power drain higher for read than write?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, power-supply, power, throughput

The [graphs on this page](https://www.anandtech.com/show/12263/the-crucial-mx500-500gb-review/5) show that the Crucial MX500 SSD has a peak measured power draws of:

- Read - 2.4W
- Write - 2.0W

Why would sustained random reads draw more power than sustained random writes?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably some extra level of parallelism going on for reading that is not possible during writing.

SSDs tend to have read speeds that are two (or more) times as high as their write speeds and so while writing may in theory require more power per unit read or written, reading can do more actual work per unit of time.

Reading can have more data being pulled from all the flash chips together and being marshalled out to the computer at once, writing is at the whim of the lower write speeds that are a fact of how they work.

So even if reads consume half (or less) the power of writing, the fact that reads can be two or more times faster can result in an overall higher instantaneous power draw.